# What are the ingredients in environmentally friendly ski/snowboard wax?

Tags: equipment, maintenance, snowboarding, skiing

I've recently been interested in learning about the different types of waxes for skis and snowboards, and after reading about the damage that has been done by fluorocarbon wax (and others), I'm hesitant to use wax from certain companies.

Some companies advertise their wax as being "eco friendly." What are common ingredients for ski/snowboard wax that are not harmful to the environment?

Comment: This is a great question.  The websites for these eco-friendly waxes all happily list the things that are *not* in their waxes, but they don't seem to reveal what *is* in the waxes.

Comment: You should just use wax from candles or animal fat. The company ones have things that might make your snow board performance better but its not good.

Answer (score -2):

Lib Tech Bio wax says it is made from Soy Beans.  Bluebird also makes wax from soy, hemp or coconut oil.